Dns to view website on smartphone with nordvpn
I have NordVPN on my phone and on my Raspberry Pi. Both connected to the meshnet. On Raspberry Pi I have Nginx and on localhost you can see a site and I can also see it from the phone when I am connected to the meshnet with nordvpn by putting the name of the raspberry or the IP on the meshnet on the browser.
I created a new site on nginx and I can see this site via the domain test.dev on the raspberry having modified the hosts file.
I would also like to see it from the phone using the same domain when I am connected to the meshnet.
I tried to set the IP of the meshnet of the raspberry as the DNS of nordvpn on the nordvpn application and did the configuration with dnsmasq for address= etc with the IP of the meshnet and also with the local IP on the raspberry pi but from the phone I still can't see it. From the DNS settings of the phone it doesn't let me add DNS without a name, so I guess private ones can't be added
Can I do what I want? What I'm doing wrong?
